# Successful use of index in mysql fuzzy query? Shouldn't the key attribute be null?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-like, explain

I created a table `test_demo`,and added 5000+ datas

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_test`;
CREATE TABLE `tb_online_disk_mgmt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `node_name` varchar(512) NOT NULL COMMENT '节点名称',
  `node_level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '节点所在层',
  `area_code` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '区域代码',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `area_level_name` (`area_code`,`node_level`,`node_name`(255)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `area_name` (`area_code`,`node_name`(255))
```

)

Fuzzy query will not use the index, will perform a full table query.But in mysql5.5 i try.Through the result of the picture `like "%xxx%"` doesn't use index,and searched all datas.But the key in explain result show the key_name `area_level_name`, why this happened?

[image]

Comment: Your question does not show much research, and a five minute search of the site would have turned up a lot of help.

Comment: Thats simple: the index `area_name` indexes the column `node_name`, and a `LIKE` condition that has a wildcard at the end is able to use that index (it was built up using the first 255 chars of that column).

The other query can not make use of that index, it has to perform a full table scan to find matching rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nico Haase. The second sql don't use index is right ,I konw this. But I use EXPLAIN in mysql why the attribute key's value is ```area_level_name```. Shouldn't it be null??

Comment: The question isn't duplicate~~~I searched answers for a long time on net.Other answers tell us how to use index when we do fuzzy query in mysql.No response is ok for my question....

Answer (score 0):

A leading wildcard (`%`) prevents use of `node_name` in any index).  However, it could use any index *beginning with* `area_code`, thereby limited the tests to about 8274 rows.  (I cannot explain why it used `area_level_name` instead of `area_name -- it usually picks the 'smaller' index.)

"Prefix indexing" (`INDEX ... name(255) ...`) is rarely useful; you found one of the cases where it can be used (`LIKE "me%"`).

More in my [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Get.Thanks a lot.